# jQuery UI Tabs: Set Tabs to full page size

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I thought this would be a simple project but it looks like it's a lot more complicated. Searched bo I'm trying to create jQuery UI tabs that take up the whole page. So the width and height of the tabs should be set to the size of the browser.

Can anyone suggest any examples or tutorial on doing this using jQuery UI tabs?

Answer (score 8):

Using the http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ tabs, there is a top-level `<div>` block enclosing the list that defines the tabs and a `<div>` for each tab, like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Tab 1 Content HERE</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Tab 2 Content HERE</div>
</div>
```

To set the size of the tab widget, add style (attribute or css) to the top `<div>`:

```
<div id="tabs" style="width:100%; height:100%">
```

Exactly what style you should apply will depend on your desired page layout.

Comment: I have seen many complicated solution which cost me a lot of time and dose not work until finding your answer.

Comment: Is there any reason why this would no longer work, using the latest jQuery (3.1)? I can set the height in pixels, but percent doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Jodes can you put together a pair of examples with the same code / different lib versions?

Comment: @MrTrick I fixed it - I had to set HTML and body height and width to 100%, and the same for any containers between them and the tabs. My apology - I hadn't tried it in previous jQuery versions, which my last comment implied